# Problema evento doble click en datagrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datagrid

Hola tengo un problema que si hago doble click en un header del datagrid me devuelve error en el evento CellDoubleClick, a mi me interesa que el evento sea valido para todas las celdas menos los headers, probé con e.RowIndex>0 o e.RowIndex<>-1 pero no funciona, alguna sugerencia??

Dejo el código de lo que estuve probando

```
  private void AgendaSemanal_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{      
 if (AgendaSemanal.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "Libre" && e.RowIndex!=-1)// tambien probe con e.RowIndex>0
{//instrucciones}

}
```

También adjunto el error que me esta provocando: Esto se debe a que e.RowIndex vale -1 cuando hago doble click en el header pero no entiendo porque no me deja evaluarlo en el IF

**Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' en mscorlib.dll
Información adicional: El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.**

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer que te muestre por consola el valor que devuelve e de la Row y Cell cuando haces doble clic ? Así podrías saber cuál tiene que ser la condición

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que cuando utilizas el operador `&&`(and) en primer lugar se evalúa el operador de la izquierda y después, si éste es válido, el de la derecha.

En el operador de la izquierda estás intentando acceder al valor de la celda y después, en el de la derecha, compruebas que no sea la fila de cabecera. Deberías hacerlo al revés:

```
private void AgendaSemanal_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{      
     if ( e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
        AgendaSemanal.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "Libre")
        {//instrucciones}
}
```